# Blender 2.8 which rendering + engine will give me what I want

Tags: rendering, light

In Blender 2.8, I am trying to create a .png file of my scene.  I have been using Render > Render Image but I don't get any reasonable result (either all dark, or colors wrong, etc).  I have tried various combinations of engines and settings using the 'Z' hotkey, as follows, but I keep getting results that are obviously bad both in Viewport and in the final rendered image.

My question:  what settings/engine/whatever do I need to use to both (a) get the light/lamp working and (b) get an image that looks right and (c) having something that works as a final image?

This is what I am starting with, set to "Render" (from the 'Z' hotkey) with the Workbench engine.  Problem = the light/lamp isn't doing anything:

[image: Render + Workbench]

In the next image, I changed the engine to Eevee.  Now the light/lamp works, but the text and green color are gone.

[image: Render + Eevee]

In the final image, I changed the engine to Cycles.  Basically the same problem as picture #2.

[image: Render + Cycles]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Workbench engine isn't meant for lighting so this isn't suitable. For Cycles and Eevee you have to create a material. You can do that in the *Shading* workspace.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have a material that exists in layout workspace.  Is there an easy way to reassign or import it into the shading workspace, rather than recreating it altogether?

Comment: @vndep No there isn't. The workspace engine doesn't use the node system cycles and eevee have.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  If you know python, I would greatly appreciate any suggestions you would have regarding this post of mine:  "https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146189/python-2-8-how-to-assign-a-material-in-shading-versus-layout-workspace"